# How to modify the zabbix script?

Tags: python, linux, shell, email, zabbix

I use zabbix  as a monitor, but i have a problem,
when the zabbix send Alarm email,then the email would send by SMS to my iphone.
If the email title is Japanese or Chinese.
the sms is Disorder Code. Here is the scripts,how to modify it?

```
 #!/usr/bin/python26
 #coding:utf-8
 import smtplib
 from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 import sys
 mail_host = 'smtp.189.cn'
 mail_user = 'tom_a'
 mail_pass = '123456'
 mail_postfix = '189.cn'
 def send_mail(to_list,subject,content):
   me = mail_user+"<"+mail_user+"@"+mail_postfix+">"
   msg = MIMEText(content,_subtype='plain',_charset='utf-8')
   msg['Subject'] = subject
   msg['From'] = me
   msg['to'] = to_list
   try:
     s = smtplib.SMTP()
     s.connect(mail_host)
     s.login(mail_user,mail_pass)
     s.sendmail(me,to_list,msg.as_string())
     s.close()
     return True
   except Exception,e:
     print str(e)
     return False
 if __name__ == "__main__":
   send_mail(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Instead look at the SMS functionality built right into Zabbix and use that. Instead of trying to hack into the email sending functionality (I think), just [write yourself a script](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/notifications/media/script) to work with the SMS provider of your choice.

Then add this to your alert options for the triggers you care about. For example, you might want it to run only for Disaster level triggers.

Comment: I know zabbix can use sms,but  i use emali,then email would send to my iphone,because it is free,189 mail or 139 mail has a free fucnction,so i want to send email,then the email woul send to my iphone autolly.

Comment: So what on earth do you want help with?